# why I do not get the column name recognised since I have it into my tibble when attempting replace_with_na_all?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am attempting to assign NA to certain categorical values in my tibble, with tidyverse, in R.
Yet, my column name isn't picked up.

Here is a fake data I have:

```
structure(list(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", 
"8", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20"), health_care_worker = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), how_unwell = c(1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 
6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Comorbidity_one = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Asthma (managed with an inhaler)", "Diabetes Type 2", 
"High Blood Pressure (hypertension)", "No", "None"), class = "factor"), 
    Comorbidity_two = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Obesity"), class = "factor"), Comorbidity_three = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "No", "No"), Comorbidity_four = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Comorbidity_five = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Comorbidity_six = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Comorbidity_seven = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Comorbidity_eight = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Comorbidity_nine = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

here is the code I have written to get my desired output:

```
na_strings <- c("Diarrhoea", "Long Standing Health Issues", "No","Yes", "0", "4", "15", "No", "Self-Isolating With No Symptoms",
                "Showing Symptoms But Not Tested", "Mild", "Moderate")

data_replace_na <- fake_data %>%
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.Comorbidity_one %in% na_strings,
                      condition = ~.Comorbidity_two %in% na_strings, 
                      condition = ~. Comorbidity_three %in% na_strings)
```

This is the first error I get:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                      condition = ~.Comorbidity_two %in% na_strings, 
                      condition = ~. Comorbidity_three"
```

if I remove my second condition and third one, then I get this error:

```
Error in .Comorbidity_one %in% na_strings : 
  object '.Comorbidity_one' not found
```

Does someone know why I cannot succeed? This seem to be two-folded problem. First, it does not pick up on my column name and second, how then I can succeed assigning the categories of those variables to the NA?

Comment: I assume that you wanted to only set NAs in some columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `condition` is looping over each column as it takes anonymous function based on the documentation

> condition - A condition required to be TRUE to set NA. Here, the condition is specified with a formula, following the syntax: ~.x {condition}. For example, writing ~.x < 20 would mean "where a variable value is less than 20, replace with NA".

Also, based on the documentation, it is taking the whole dataset and there is no provision for subset of columns

> This function takes a dataframe and replaces all values that meet the condition specified as an NA value, following a special syntax.

By checking the source code, it is doing the loop with `map` on all the columns

```
...
purrr::map_dfc(data, ~na_set(.x, condition))
...
```

So, unless we `select` the columns before, it would be executing on all the columns

```
fake_data %>%
  replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% na_strings)
```

---

If we need to replace only selected columns use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
fake_data %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('Comorbidity'), 
               ~ replace(., . %in% na_strings, NA)))
```

Comment: thank you. It worked nicely. I am in need of the second code. I also want tick this as the answer. In 2 min I can actually

Comment: thank you. It worked nicely. And indeed the answer is just amazing!!